# How does the ParentViewController display a ChildViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've created an array of `ChildViewControllers`, but how to make the `ParentViewController` display one of the `ChildViewController(arrayChildViewController[0])`?

In the ParentViewController:

```
[self addChildViewController:arrayChildViewController[0]]; [arrayChildViewController[0] didMoveToParentViewController:self];

[self addChildViewController:arrayChildViewController[1]]; [arrayChildViewController[1] didMoveToParentViewController:self];

[self addChildViewController:arrayChildViewController[2]]; [arrayChildViewController[2] didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

In the arrayChildViewController[1]:(arrayChildViewController is a navigationController,i add a UIImagePickerController,here is it's delegate method)

```
 - (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
  //[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];        
  [self.parentViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
  [self.parentViewController.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
   }
```

The parentViewController can't display arrayChildViewController[1],It becomes arrayChildViewController[0]. Hope i make it clear.

Comment: Are you using a navigationController?

Comment: @laura-wen i have posted answer please try it.

Comment: @laura-wen please replay.

Comment: @laura-wen Please share your code...

Comment: @laura-wen If you share the code i will definitely help you. why are you not sharing code. how to create array of view controllers.

Comment: This is arrayChildViewController[1]:                                                                      - (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
//    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [self.parentViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    [self.parentViewController.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
    
} The parentVieController can't display arrayChildViewController[1],It becomes arrayChildViewController[0] . Hope i make it clear....

Comment: @AshokLondhe  below is my code .sorry,i'm not good at use the website

Comment: @laura-wen no need to write self.parentViewController.ChildViewController..    instead write self.childViewController and try.

Comment: @laura-wen yar i have posted answer and it will run perfectly you try it and relay me . i am waiting for your replay..

Comment: @ZeMoon  yes,my childViewController is a navigationController

Comment: @AshokLondhe  Actually,It's wasn't me,i even can't vote down and vote up:-(,because my reputation is below 15. It was late last night,you know,so i came home.I've tried,It does work,thank you very much.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Try below code.. it will help you.**

**Code:**

```
[self.parentViewController addChildViewController:childViewControllers[0]];
[self.parentViewController addChildViewController:childViewControllers[1]];
[self.parentViewController.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
```

Comment: @laura-wen share your code so that i can see it and try to help you.

Comment: hi.. friend if there is any mistake in my answer please inform me instead of down voting so that next time  i am not doing same mistake.i have posted this answer after running it on my device. and it run perfectly.

Comment: friends this is correct code why are you down voting.. before down voting first run and check it. this code run perfectly.

Comment: =.= Actually,It's wasn't me,i even can't vote down and vote up:-(,because my reputation is below 15. It was late last night,you know,so i came home.I've tried,It does work,thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add it like this and move it to parent view controller

```
[self addChildViewController:arrayChildViewController[0]];
[arrayChildViewController[0] didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Comment: I've already did that.sorry,I didn't make it clear. I add three childViewControllers to parentViewController,but how to display arrayChildViewController[0]?Thanks.

Comment: @stefan salacity the last line of your code give the error.

Comment: Might have been an error since I was writing it from the top of my head. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: it gives error... "Property view not found on type id"

Comment: @laura-wen   remove this line [self.parentViewController.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:1];   instead of it write this line  [self.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:1];

Answer (score 0):

In the`ParentViewController` Write the below code:

```
[self addChildViewController:arrayChildViewController[0]];
[arrayChildViewController[0] didMoveToParentViewController:self];

[self addChildViewController:arrayChildViewController[1]];
[arrayChildViewController[1] didMoveToParentViewController:self];

[self addChildViewController:arrayChildViewController[2]];
[arrayChildViewController[2] didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

This is arrayChildViewController[1]:

```
 - (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker { //         [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];   [self.parentViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];  [self.parentViewController.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
 }
```

The `parentVieController` can't display `arrayChildViewController[1]`,It becomes `arrayChildViewController[0]`.